# Complement to a subspace, in linear algebra, in topology, in functional analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

DEFINITION 1.

In a linear vector space $\mathbb{V}$, a complement to a subspace $\mathbb{W}$ is a subspace ${\mathbb{W}}^{\,\prime}$ such that
$$
{\mathbb{W}}\oplus {\mathbb{W}}^{\,\prime}\;=\;{\mathbb{V}}\;.\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (1)
$$
By this definition, $\mathbb{V}$ and the zero subspace $\{\vec{0}\}$ are one another's unique complements.

QUESTION 1:

Would it be right of me to say that in this simple case each subspace has a unique complement, no matter whether the dimensions are countable or uncountable?
$$
$$
DEFINITION 2.

If a linear vector space ${\mathbb{V}}$ is endowed with an inner product, a complement to its subspace ${\mathbb{W}}$ is called *orthogonal complement*, and denoted as ${\mathbb{W}}^{\perp}$, if
$$
{\mathbb{W}}^{\perp}\,=\,\left\{w'\in {\mathbb{V}}\;:\;\;(w',\,w)=0\;\;\mbox{for}\,\forall\; w\in{\mathbb{W}}   \right\}\;\,.\qquad\qquad\qquad (2)
$$

QUESTION 2:

Would it be right of me to say that in this case, too, each subspace has a unique complement, no matter what dimensions?

QUESTION 3:

Will ${\mathbb{W}}^{\perp}$ from the 2nd definition coincide with $W^{\,\prime}$ from the 1st definition?
$$
$$
I understand that in general the existence of a complement is not warranted. E.g. if we are dealing with Banach spaces (those having a norm and complete), we have to make them also Hilbert, if we wish every closed subspace in them to be complemented.

QUESTION 4:

At what point exactly do things break down? With what minimal additional structures do I have to equip my spaces $\mathbb{V}$ and $\mathbb{W}$ to no longer be sure that $\mathbb{W}\subset \mathbb{V}$ is always complemented?

Comment: What do you mean by "unique supplement"? You have only defined "complement".

Comment: Consider the $x$-axis in $\mathbb R^2$. Any line other than the $x$-axis is a linear complement, so the complement of the $x$-axis is not unique.

Comment: @MarkSaving Sorry, it was a slip of the pen. Thank you for noticing it. I meant complement, of course. Now corrected.

Comment: @Nico , thank you. You have answered my first question. (And, indirectly, the 2nd and 3rd.) I still hope to get an answer for my 4th question from someone.

Comment: Skimming https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemented_subspace it seems to me that it's the introduction of a topology, and a requirement that the addition map from $W\times W'$ to $V$ be a homeomorphism, that result in uncomplimented subspaces.

Comment: @Nico ,, On second thoughts, I would question your answer. My Q1 was about a space lacking a dot product. So, why wouldn't we say that, for a subspace defined by a vector $\hat{\bf{e}}$, its unique complement is the subspace drawn on all the vectors different from $\hat{\bf{e}}$ or its multiples?

Comment: If $V$ is a vector space, Michael, and $W$ is the subspace generated by a vector $w$, then the set of all vectors different from $w$ and its multiples is not a subspace. For one thing, it doesn't contain the zero vector, since that's a multiple of $w$. For another, aside from the trivial case where $V=W$, it's not closed under addition. Anyway, any thoughts on my comment about complemented subspaces?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, you are right. It indeed is not closed under addition. Thank you for this comment -- and also for the link to wiki article. It contains quite a bit of food for thought.

Comment: @GerryMyerson , sorry to bother you again. While a *linear* complement is not unique, would it be right of me to say that the *orthogonal* complement ${\mathbb{W}}^{\,\perp}$ **is** unique? (The spaces ${\mathbb{W}}\subset{\mathbb{V}}$ are not topological here. Just spaces with an inner product.)

Comment: Yes, because there is a criterion that specifies exactly which vectors get to be in the orthogonal complement.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, this is what I thought. Thank you!